# Is repentance required for salvation?

Tags: soteriology, repentance

I know that through faith alone I am saved.  But is repentance a requirement for that salvation as a part of my faith?  Is repentance a single act, or should it be continuous?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Short Answer, YES; Long Answer, YES YES

**First we need to define what repentance is.**

The word in Greek is *Metanoeo* which means: To change ones mind. The word repent in Hebrew is *Nacham* which means to: to be sorry, be moved to pity, have compassion.

- Repentance is a state of mind, of sorrow over your actions.

Now that we understand the word's definition we need to understand the context that the word is used in. Here in the old testament is one verse, of many, that defines repentance.

> Ezekiel 18:30 NKJV
>
> “Therefore, you Israelites, I will judge each of you according to your
> own ways, declares the Sovereign LORD. Repent! Turn away from all your
> offenses; then sin will not be your downfall.

- Repentance is to turn away from all of your offenses, to turn away from sin.

So you can see that repentance is a mindful state of abhorrence to the things that you have done. The bible says that we need to prove this mindful state by our actions. Have a look:

> Acts 26:20 niv
>
> First to those in Damascus, then to those in Jerusalem and in all
> Judea, and to the Gentiles also, I preached that they should repent
> and turn to God and prove their repentance by their deeds.

- Your turning away from sin is proven by what you do.

**Repentance is: Having a changed mind that turns you from the things that you were once doing in order that you may do the opposite.**

### What does God say about Repentance?

We are commanded to repent of our sins.

> Job 36:10 niv
>
> He makes them [his children] listen to correction and commands them to repent of
> their evil.
>
> Acts 17:30 niv
>
> In the past God overlooked such ignorance, but now he commands all
> people everywhere to repent.

### What does Jesus say about Repentance?

Here we see Jesus talking about the final judgement, he's giving us insight into what He will say and do on that day.

> **Matthew 7:21-23** (NKJV)
>
> 21 “Not everyone who says to Me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ shall enter the kingdom
> of heaven, **but he who does the will of My Father in heaven.** 22 Many
> will say to Me in that day, ‘Lord, Lord, have we not prophesied in
> Your name, cast out demons in Your name, and done many wonders in Your
> name?’ 23 And then I will declare to them, ‘**I never knew you; depart
> from Me, you who practice lawlessness!**’

We know that sin is lawlessness. Christ is literally saying that if you practice sin He will have nothing to do with you, you did not know Him and He did not know you. In this next verse you see Jesus commanding us to repent, He does this constantly throughout his testimony on this earth.

> Matthew 4:17 (NIV)
>
> From that time on Jesus began to preach, "Repent, for the kingdom of
> heaven is near."
>
> Luke 3:3
>
> He went into all the country around the Jordan, preaching a baptism of repentance for the > forgiveness of sins.

It's interesting what Luke says here, a baptism of repentance FOR the forgiveness of sins. If we put this altogether with what else we have learned so far, we see that if we turn from our sins then God will be faithful and forgive us for those sins.

So if this is true, then the opposite should also be true. **If we continue to sin then we will go to Hell?** Let's see if what the Bible says.

> **Hebrews 10:26-27** (NIV)
>
> 26 If we deliberately keep on sinning after we have received the
> knowledge of the truth, no sacrifice for sins is left, 27 but only a
> fearful expectation of judgment and of  raging fire that will consume
> the enemies of God.

Finally God says that He stands FIRM on this very statement. He will not change His mind.

> **2 Timothy 2:19** (NIV)
>
> 19 Nevertheless, God’s solid foundation stands firm, sealed with this
> inscription: “The Lord knows those who are his,” and, “Everyone who
> confesses the name of the Lord must turn away from wickedness.”

### Assurance of salvation as it relates to repentance

> 1 John 1:6-76 NIV
>
> If we claim to have fellowship with him yet walk in the darkness [evil], we
> lie and do not live by the truth. 7 But if we walk in the light [love], as he
> is in the light, we have fellowship with one another, and the blood of
> Jesus, his Son, purifies us from all sin.

If you continue to sin then the truth [Holy spirit, God, Jesus] is not in you.

> 1 John 2:4-5 NIV
>
> The man who says, "I know him," but does not do what he commands is a
> liar, and the truth is not in him. But if anyone obeys his word, God's
> love is truly made complete in him.

If you say that you know God, but you continue to sin, not loving as you were commanded, then you are a liar and [Holy spirit, God, Jesus] is not in you.

### Repentance is a struggle against the desires of your flesh

> Revelation 2:19
>
> I know your deeds, your love and faith, your service and perseverance,
> and that you are now doing more than you did at first.

You will not be perfect right away, you will go through a lot of discipline and correction from God, so that you may produce more and more fruit throughout the days of your life. Persevere in your repentance.

> Hebrews 10:36
>
> You need to persevere so that when you have done the
> will of God, you will receive what he has promised.

Comment: http://www.gotquestions.org/repentance.html states "To repent, in relation to salvation, is to change your mind in regard to Jesus Christ". This seems to be totally different from what you posted. Do you agree with that page? If so, how does this post reconcile with that?

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to @JonathonByrd for his answer! I would just like to add a verse that I recently stumbled on in Luke:

> JUST AT that time there [arrived] some people who informed Jesus about
>   the Galileans whose blood Pilate had mixed with their sacrifices.
>   And He replied by saying to them, Do you think that these Galileans
>   were greater sinners than all the other Galileans because they have
>   suffered in this way?
>   I tell you, No; but **unless you repent** (change
>   your mind for the better and heartily amend your ways, with abhorrence
>   of your past sins), **you will all likewise perish and be lost
>   eternally**.
>   Or those eighteen on whom the tower in Siloam fell and
>   killed them--do you think that they were more guilty offenders
>   (debtors) than all the others who dwelt in Jerusalem?
>   I tell you,
>   No; but **unless you repent** (change your mind for the better and
>   heartily amend your ways, with abhorrence of your past sins), **you will
>   all likewise perish and be lost eternally**.
>   Luke 13:1-5 - Amplified

The moment someone truly accepts Jesus, they have remorse for their sins, and they are saved. Once we have our salvation, we cannot lose it (John 10:28-29). However, you will continue to sin, so therefore you should continuously repent for those sins. Not necessarily for salvation, but to have a better relationship with the Lord.

Also, when we deliberately sin, and don't repent to God (maybe because we feel ashamed and/or don't really feel sorry because we keep doing it), we become more numb to the sin and it brings less conviction and takes us farther from God each time we do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a requirement... or better, a precondition.  In order to be saved, you have to accept Jesus sacrifice.  But for this, you have to realize that this sacrifice was necessary.  And for *that*, you have to realize... your sin.

Now... you could accept your sin ("Yup, bad stuff")... without leaving it.  Makes sense?  Don't think so, but people *may* be wanting to see it that way.  Here, the gospel (and that means, Jesus) is quite clear: you cannot accept the gift of life but keep to your old ways.  Doesn't work that way (and it should be quite obvious why... would you forgive someone if you knew he'd keep on doing what you just forgave him?)

As to the second part of your question: it is both.  It is a single act, when you accept Jesus as your Savior and Lord.  And it's a sort-of ongoing process... because, being imperfect sinners, we always fall.  So, we have to pick ourselves up and continue (stumbling) on.  That means repentance every time we fall.

But beware: do *not* dwell on sin.  No matter how big and nasty it was, it is **already** forgiven.  Jesus died *once*, he doesn't die again every time you need forgiveness.  The longer you dwell on it, the longer the enemy can keep you away from God.  Doing whatever it was is bad enough, but staying away from God because of it makes it worse.   He wants us close, and be close to us, *always*.

Standard Disclaimer: I do not speak for any tradition, denomination, or what-have-you.  Authority?  Ask God to show you if what I say is true.  Then, either he confirms or he doesn't.  That's all.  (Dang, why doesn't this thing not have support for a signature or similar...)

Comment: I don't suppose you can back up at least a couple of your points with Scripture? :)

Comment: please provide scripture.

Comment: Feel free to edit or propose edits, but I generally don't hunt for verses before I post, sorry.  AFAIK, quotations are not required (unlike on skeptics.SE).  And some of this isn't "scriptural", it's just using my experience and my God-given brains.

Comment: Why should Christianity.SE be held to a lower standard of excellence when it comes to contending for our faith than anyone on Skeptics.SE?

Comment: Verses are not required, but if your answer claims to represent Christianity and other Christians contest the basis of your answer you are going to have to be able to defend it. Purely personal viewpoints that do not claim to speak for any larger group are [not encouraged](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/201/30) and subject to extra scrutiny and hence the need for references. You don't want just any hobo coming along and telling other people about what _you_ believe when _he_ doesn't know the same Jesus _you_ do, do you?

Comment: -1 This answer badly needs references to justify it.

Answer (score -2):

Repentance from sin is required for salvation. We know this since the demons "believe".  They will not be saved since God has prophesied their destiny in Revelation and elsewhere. Repentance from sin does not mean sinless perfection, it means a true, heartfelt decision that results in a change of behavior.

However, faith and repentance go hand in hand.  If a person has no faith, why would he need or want to repent from sin? God's kindness in the forgiveness of sins leads us to repentance from sin.  When we are saved, the Spirit of God gives us the power and desire to do so.

Comment: Welcome! Sadly, this answer seems to just express your opinion, which isn't what this site is about: here we focus on explaining and learning about the documented beliefs of Christian groups, not individuals.  Please take a minute to learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and review how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Though your answer does address the question, the question itself is an old one, and doesn't specify the group or denomination of Christians whose answer it wants. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) If you edit your answer to provide a denominational perspective and some quotes from faith statements or theologians in that denomination, it would be on-topic here.

Comment: About your suggested edit, that belongs in a comment rather than as an edit to the answer. If you log in using the same account, you can always comment on your own posts even if you don't have the reputation to comment on others' posts.