# How important is a "moment" of conversion?

Tags: conversion

Some people can specify the day and hour when they became Christians. Others were brought up Christians and say that, though they are Christian now, they cannot specify exactly *when* the change took place.

Is it important to be able to specify **the moment** of conversion?

**Update:** this is not about remembering the date and time but about being able to specify the moment.

Comment: Possibly related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/is-the-sinners-prayer-important-for-salvation-and-why

Comment: The answer to this question is unfortunately highly dependent on tradition... the Reformed and Oneness traditions, for example, will approach this question very differently.